# How can I update my app.config file without republishing Azure Worker Role Service

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I want to change a specific value in my app.config appSettings for my Cloud Service Worker Role.  I don't want to republish my service so as to allow it to keep running.  How can I do this either from Visual Studio or Powershell or any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only change values in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file without a redeploy, so it is recommended to store the settings in that file, instead of app.config, for a Cloud Service.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-configure/

Comment: So it would seem the app.config file for a cloud service looses some of it's traditional value as a place to store information that can be edited without reinstalling the application.  Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, for cloud services the part of "a place to store information that can be edited without reinstalling the application" is replaced by the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file. By using `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(settingName)` you can get the value from the proper file (ServiceConfiguration.cscfg when running in a cloud service, or app.config when not).

Answer (score 0):

You should update the staging version of your app, validate it works correctly, then just swap staging and production.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-manage/#how-to-swap-deployments-to-promote-a-staged-deployment-to-production